# If $ \frac{x}{b-c} = \frac{y}{c-a} = \frac{z}{a-b}$, Prove that $x+y+z$ $=0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> > Question  If $$ \frac{x}{b-c} = \frac{y}{c-a} = \frac{z}{a-b} $$ Prove that $x+y+z$ $=0$

I've attmempted this question by cross multiplying so that

$$ x(c-a)(a-b) = y(b-c)(a-b) = (b-c)(c-a)z $$

but that did not work

I also tried splitting the equation so

$ \frac{x}{b-c} = \frac{y}{c-a}$  and $\frac{y}{c-a} = \frac{z}{a-b}$

and tried forming systems of equation but that didn't lead me to the proof as well...

Could someone please help!

Comment: Set each ratio $=k$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

\begin{align}
x+y+z&=\frac{b-c}{a-b}z+\frac{c-a}{a-b}z+z\\
&=z\left(\frac{b-c+c-a+a-b}{a-b}\right)\\
&=z\cdot 0\\
&=0
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Using $k$-method, let $\displaystyle \frac{x}{b-c}=\frac{y}{c-a}=\frac{z}{a-b}=k$, then $\displaystyle \sum_{xyz} x=\sum_{abc} (b-c)k=0$.

Comment: That's the easiest way. And of course, there's a geometric explanation - given a line and a plane in the canonical form, check if the line lies on the plane.